# Unity TextMeshProUGUI Text by Page

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine

I want to get the text of a TextMeshProUGUI component of the current displayed page. I tried this:

```
foreach (var page in InstructionText.textInfo.pageInfo)
            {
                Debug.Log(page.firstCharacterIndex + " : " + page.lastCharacterIndex);
                m_TextsPerPage.Add(InstructionText.text.Substring(page.firstCharacterIndex, page.lastCharacterIndex - page.firstCharacterIndex + 1));
            }
```

with

```
private List<string> m_TextsPerPage = new List<string>();
```

but `page.firstCharacterIndex` and `page.lastCharacterIndex` are both 0 no matter which input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`page.firstCharacterIndex` and `page.lastCharacterIndex` do work but their values do not get updated instantly so you have to wait until it gets updated so adding a yield solves the issue:

```
while (InstructionText.textInfo.pageInfo[0].lastCharacterIndex == 0)
                yield return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

tag your uiGUI. search for the tag, `GameObject.FindObjectWithTag()` then do `GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>()`

then you can access/read/change its `.text`

Comment: I have no problem getting the text component, it just seems that page.firstCharacterIndex and page.lastCharacterIndex does not work.